# NSURLConnection HTTPBody setting with null

Tags: ios

I've to provide POST requests with REST Api. I'm providing the POST values as dictionary. Using NSURLConnection for establishing the connection. Also converting to NSDATA using NSJSONSerialization.

Below is the code snippet of my connection.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:restApiURL];

/* Specify that it will be a POST request */
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

/* Specify request timeout */
request.timeoutInterval = 300;

/* This is how we set header fields */
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSData *requestBodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

/* create the connection */
self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

/* ensure the connection was created */
if (self.connection)
{
    /* initialize the buffer */
    self.buffer = [NSMutableData data];

    /* start the request */
    [self.connection start];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
}
```

When tested the **requestBodyData**, it is having the same value which i'm sending. But after setting the body of the request, the values are becoming null.

I received the response as ***"Operation could not be completed"***. But the api is working fine in browsers. So for checking, now the service returns the values received. When printing the received response the values of the post parameters are null.

Kindly help me in posting proper values to rest service.

Comment: Use Charles as a proxy to see what you are posting to your API

Comment: try to set this as NSData *requestBodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDictionary options:0 error:&error];

Comment: use Postman client or Dhc plugins to check the errors

Comment: @do u show ur restApiURL it is easy to optimize the o/p

Comment: Where do you print the requestBody? I mean the point you find the value id NULL

Comment: @Danyun, the response of the webservice been modified to print the received values, which is printing as null.

Comment: @M.SwornaVidhya your dataWithJSONObject method returns a error object if it cannot deal with the data. double check if there error message returns something